# Why do control keys (ctrl, shift, alt) not work sometimes?

Tags: 10.10, keyboard

Sometimes (about once a week) the control keys (ctrl, shift, alt) so not work anymore. They do work when I boot up, but after a while they stop working. Logging out and in again repairs it. What can cause something like that?

It is a laptop keyboard (HP EliteBook 8730w) with german layout.

Incidentally it just happened right after vmware-player crashed same as the last time. Coincidence?

Comment: What keyboard do you have? Laptop or desktop? Type? (PS/2 or USB)

Comment: It's a laptop keyboard.

Comment: Ok, and what model? Please include it in your question.

Comment: Please see if the attached solution is working for you. http://www.phpfox.com/blog/ubuntu-ctrl-key-not-working/

Comment: Right now I am not using vmware very often so I can not tell if it helps. Please write an answer formulating the fix behind your link, so I can accept it in case the problem happens again and your fix works.

Comment: Take a look at http://serverfault.com/questions/64859/vmware-in-linux-breaks-my-alt-ctrl-and-or-shift-keys-how-do-i-fix-it